# PL/SQL Hierarchical Profiler in Autonomous Database

Tags: oracle, oracle-autonomous-db, oracle21c

How can I use the PL/SQL hierarchical profiler in an Oracle autonomous database? When I try to run the following code, I get the error "PLS-00201: identifier 'DBMS_HPROF' must be declared":

```
begin
    sys.dbms_hprof.create_tables(force_it => true);
end;
/
```

The package DBMS_HPROF exists but is not granted to any user:

```
SQL> select owner,object_name,object_type from dba_objects where object_name='DBMS_HPROF' order by 1,2,3;

OWNER   OBJECT_NAME  OBJECT_TYPE
------- ------------ -------------
PUBLIC  DBMS_HPROF   SYNONYM
SYS     DBMS_HPROF   PACKAGE
SYS     DBMS_HPROF   PACKAGE BODY

SQL> select * from dba_tab_privs where table_name = 'DBMS_HPROF';

no rows selected
```

If this was a local database, I would logon as SYS and run `grant execute on sys.dbms_hprof to my_username;`. But as far as I know, there is no way to run a command as SYS on an Oracle autonomous database.

If this was Amazon RDS, I could probably run a command like `RDSADMIN.RDSADMIN_UTIL.GRANT_SYS_OBJECT(...`. But as far as I know, there is no such package on an Oracle autonomous database. None of the DBMS_CLOUD* packages seem to have what I'm looking for either.

I'm using Oracle 21c Autonomous Data Warehouse on the Always Free tier.

Is there a way to run the PL/SQL hierarchical profiler on the cloud? Or am I stuck using the older profiler as a work around?

Comment: dbms_hprof is not yet available in ADB shared. There's an enhancement request to make it available that was filed recently.

Comment: @gsalem Thanks. Is there some type of support identifier or any way for the public to track that change? If so, feel free to add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try following MOS ER: 34369019. As for all MOS documents, this requires a login.

Comment: Nothing shows up in My Oracle Support when I search for that number. Is it a private document only available to your organization?

Comment: That's why I said 'try following'! I was not sure if it was published or not.

Comment: We treat this as a bug and it will be implemented very soon in 19c, 21c to follow. Unfortunately we cannot give a more exact timeline at this moment. Seeing that one in MOS won't tell you more. We'll keep you updated.